# Saving gamestate on HTML5 Cordova. Can't read/write with cordova-file-plugin

Tags: android, file, cordova, filesystems

I've got an HTML5 game, ported to Android via Cordova. Now I'm looking to keep the game state between sessions. I planned to do so saving the state as a .json to the persistent data directory using the cordova-plugin-file.

I'm using *Cordova 6.2.0* and *cordova-plugin-file 4.2.0*, and I run my code after the `deviceReady` event.

To write and read the files I tried to apply the examples from the [offical documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/index.html) (which are a nest of callbacks coming without useful explanation...). I could apply the "create persistent file" example to run under Chromium after manually requesting quota, else `requestFileSystem` fails with "Security error: too many file accesses" (sorry, don't have it handy verbatim). On Firefox, `requestFileSystem` fails with the same error regardless what I tried. On Android `fileEntry.getFile` fails with "File not found". Directly calling the `writeFile` or `readFile` methods will, once again, result in the security error in all scenarios.

Does anybody have some good example code (or helpful tutorial) for my problem:

1. Read a persistent .json file (or text file, I'll need to parse it anyway) if it exists (no excessive check for existance neccessary, simply throwing if the file doesn't exist is enough)
2. Write a persistent .json file (or text file)
3. Work on Android, and possibly cross-browser

Better examples (like Raymond Camden's) are quite outdated and throw different errors.

I'm also ready to accept a working cross-platform solution that avoids Cordova plugins alltogether.

Comment: Basic working sample of file operations -https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_File_Operations

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution is using Local Storage and you can find its documentation here:
[Local Storage](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.7.0/cordova/storage/localstorage/localstorage.html)

In my idea, Local Storage is very fast, easy and secure.

Comment: Oh. I had fought the file-plugin so hard I had completely forgotten about that one. That's, of course, the simplest solution possible. Thanks for the reminder!